# getting wrong output with certain input

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner ; 
public class printH 
    {
        public static void main( String[] args )
        {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in) ;
            System.out.print("Please enter the height of H: ") ;
            int height = in.nextInt() ;
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
            int heightThird = findThird(height);
            for (int i = 0; i < heightThird; i++) 
            {
                printTopAndBottom(heightThird);     
            }
            for (int j = 0; j<= 1; j++)
            {
                printMidH(height, heightThird);
            } 
            for (int i = 0; i < heightThird; i++) 
            {
                printTopAndBottom(heightThird);     
            }  
        }
        public static int findThird(int height3)
        {
            if(height3 >= 4)
            {
                height3 = (height3 + 2) / 3 ;
            }
        return height3 ;
        }
        public static void printTopAndBottom(int spacingH)
        {
            String line = "";

        for (int j = 0; j < spacingH; j++) 
        {
            String currentChar = j % 2 == 0 ? "h" : " ";
            for (int i = 0; i < spacingH; i++) 
            {
                line += currentChar;
            } 
        }
    System.out.print(line + "\n");
    }
    public static int printMidH(int wide, int finalHeight)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<= 1; j++)
        {
            System.out.print("h") ;
            for(int i = 0; i<= wide; i++)
            {
                System.out.print("h") ;    
            } 
        System.out.println(); 
    } 
    return wide ;
    }
}
```

my code does the following:

1) findThird, given an integer value of 4 or more for the total height of letter H, it rounds the value up to the nearest mutiple of 3 and then computes and returns an integer that is one third of that rounded height

2)printTopAndBottom, which given that one third of rounded height value prints the top of the h with the width of the left, mid and right parts of o h, each being one third of the height of H as determinded by the firdThird method. This again is used to print the bottom

3)printMidH which given the one third of rounded height value prints the middle part of the H as wide as the rounded height and as tall as one third of the rounded height

with the input 10 it outputs: (on my program the midH matches up with the top and bottom ends just not here on stackoverflow)

```
Please enter the height of H: 10
hhhh    hhhh
hhhh    hhhh
hhhh    hhhh
hhhh    hhhh
hhhhhhhhhhhh
hhhhhhhhhhhh
hhhhhhhhhhhh
hhhhhhhhhhhh
hhhh    hhhh
hhhh    hhhh
hhhh    hhhh
hhhh    hhhh
```

however when i input 13 for example, i get the following output: (which seems incorrect)

```
hhhhh     hhhhh     hhhhh
hhhhh     hhhhh     hhhhh
hhhhh     hhhhh     hhhhh
hhhhh     hhhhh     hhhhh
hhhhh     hhhhh     hhhhh
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
hhhhh     hhhhh     hhhhh
hhhhh     hhhhh     hhhhh
hhhhh     hhhhh     hhhhh
hhhhh     hhhhh     hhhhh
hhhhh     hhhhh     hhhhh
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong here :  `for (int j = 0; j < spacingH; j++)`

Instead of iterating `heightThird`, iterate only three times.

```
public static void printTopAndBottom(int spacingH) {
        String line = "";

        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            String currentChar = j % 2 == 0 ? "h" : " ";
            for (int i = 0; i < spacingH; i++) {
                line += currentChar;
            }
        }
        System.out.print(line + "\n");
    }
```

Even one more change for `printMidH` method:

Call method `heightThird` times :

```
for (int j = 0; j < heightThird; j++) {
            printMidH(height, heightThird);
        }
```

And print 'H' `finalHeight*3` times

```
public static int printMidH(int wide, int finalHeight) {

    for (int i = 0; i < finalHeight * 3; i++) {
        System.out.print("h");
    }
    System.out.println();
    return wide;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in regards to the extra blocks off to the right is on these lines of your printTopAndBottom() method.

```
for (int j = 0; j < spacingH; j++)
    String currentChar = j % 2 == 0 ? "h" : " ";
```

This is drawing a line of 'h's for every even number from 0 to the width of each line. This means if the width is 3, it will output the blocks of 'h's like this.

```
[0] 1 [2]
[0][1][2]
[0] 1 [2]
```

But if the output width is 5, then it will generate what you're getting.

```
[0] 1 [2] 3 [4]
[0][1][2]
[0] 1 [2] 3 [4]
```

To fix this, simply replace this line

```js
for (int j = 0; j < spacingH; j++)
```

with this

```
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
```

After some testing, it looks like your code also improperly outputs the horizontal line. In your printMidH method, you shouldn't be printing "h" above this line

```
for(int i = 0; i<= wide; i++) {
```

Also, using the *wide* variable for drawing the horizontal lines of 'h's is inaccurate, as the real width has been modified to the nearest multiple of 3. Replace that line with this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < finalHeight * 3; i++) {
```